# Reverse DNS issue with Mailserver (Postfix)

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, reverse-dns, linode

My mail server is set to server.mailtuner.com, but when i try sending to a hotmail user, it goes into the spam folder.

Results on mailtester show the following reverse DNS issue: https://www.mail-tester.com/web-1bcbe&refresh=3

```
Your IP address 45.56.86.66 is associated with the domain mailtuner.com.
Nevertheless your message appears to be sent from server.mailtuner.com.

You may want to change the host name of your server to mailtuner.com.

Here are the tested values for this check:

    IP: 45.56.86.66
    HELO: server.mailtuner.com
    rDNS: mailtuner.com
```

I am using a linode VPS server if anyone is familiar with it and could help.

Comment: When updating your question, the done thing is to edit the existing one if it can be done.  If not, put the current question to bed by accepting an answer and/or deleting the question, then write a new one referencing the old question from which it arose.  Editing a question so all it does is point to a new question is completely unhelpful, not least because the existing answer now makes no sense, so I'm reverting the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Linode control panel, open the 'node in question, go to the "Remote Access" tab, and at the top next to the first part of the "Public IPs" area with the IP/gateway info where the "ssh root@your.ip" text is there is a link that says "Reverse DNS".  Click that, change the value to match your `server.mailtuner.com hostname`, save it.  Wait for up to 24 hours for the caches to clear and things to repropogate.

Happy user of Linode since the days of 24mb/ram and 6gb or so of disk being  $20 per month :)

Comment: Thanks ivanivan! i extremely need your help now! My Email is delivering fine to gmail accounts but not to hotmail! Can you please check this out brother: https://serverfault.com/questions/882469/iredmail-going-to-spam-when-sending-from-postfix-to-hotmail-and-cant-use-port