# iRedMail: Going to spam when sending from Postfix to Hotmail and Can't use port 465

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp, iredmail

I installed postfix and dovecot using iRedmail. During the installation, i supplied iRedmail with `server.mailtuner.com` as the hostname for the SMTP server.

But! My **Let's Encrypt SSL** certificate is signed for `mailtuner.com`. My main root mailserver user is `postmaster@mailtuner.com`.

**My reverse DNS:** `server.mailtuner.com` is pointing to `45.56.86.66`

**SPF:** `v=spf1 ip4:45.56.86.66 ~all`

**DMARC**: `v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@mailtuner.com`

**CNAME:** `server.mailtuner.com` aliases to `mailtuner.com`

**A records:** "" and "www" points to 45.56.86.66

**MX Records:**

```
            mailtuner.com => preference: 0
            server.mailtuner.com => preference: 10
            mail.mailtuner.com => preference: 11
```

**My DKIM** is also correctly setup by iRedMail and i also created a txt record for it.

**i got 10/10 in mailtester:** https://www.mail-tester.com/web-acvkq

**Problem!**
Emails sent from postmaster@mailtuner.com to hotmail are going to junk.

When trying to use nodemailer and set the following option headers:

```
    host: 'server.mailtuner.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // secure:true for port 465, secure:false for port 587
    auth: {
        user: 'postmaster@mailtuner.com',
        pass: 'XXXXX'
    }
});
```

I get this error:

```
{ Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: server.mailtuner.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:mailtuner.com"
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:222:17)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1110:29)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:638:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:468:38)
  reason: 'Host: server.mailtuner.com. is not in the cert\'s altnames: DNS:mailtuner.com',
  host: 'server.mailtuner.com',
  cert: 
   { subject: { CN: 'mailtuner.com' },
     issuer: 
      { C: 'US',
        O: 'Let\'s Encrypt',
        CN: 'Let\'s Encrypt Authority X3' },
     subjectaltname: 'DNS:mailtuner.com',
     infoAccess: { 'OCSP - URI': [Array], 'CA Issuers - URI': [Array] },
     modulus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
     exponent: '0x10001',
     valid_from: 'Nov  7 21:35:01 2017 GMT',
     valid_to: 'Feb  5 21:35:01 2018 GMT',
     fingerprint: '96:76:5D:D9:1C:D4:CD:50:75:60:D5:52:45:58:AB:5B:BD:D5:CB:F3',
     ext_key_usage: [ '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1', '1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2' ],
     serialNumber: '0314E704EE42C2C26F7028950BAA826401A4',
     raw: <Buffer 30 82 04 fd 30 82 03 e5 a0 03 02 01 02 02 12 03 14 e7 04 ee 42 c2 c2 6f 70 28 95 0b aa 82 64 01 a4 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 4a ... > },
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN' }
```

Changing to hostname in the header nodemailer option to `mailtuner.com` instead of `server.mailtuner.com` kind of hide the issue!

But the problem remains! My emails are sent to `**junk**` and i can't use port **`465`** to send over SSL.

**Solution?:**
Should i change the name in the Let's Encrypt certificate to server.mailtuner.com? And how to do that?

Should i also add a domain to iRedmail: `server.mailtuner.com`

and then create another user `postmaster@server.mailtuner.com`

and then add this user to my DMARC: `v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:postmaster@mailtuner.com, postmaster@server.mailtuner.com`

Answer (score 1):

Get a new letsencrypt certificate, and specify `mailtuner.com`, `server.mailtuner.com` and `mail.mailtuner.com` as the hostnames for it - ie,

`certbot certonly -d mailtuner.com -d mail.mailtuner.com -d server.mailtuner.com`

Then restart postfix adn the other services that use SSL on that system

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a single server `45.56.86.66` with all the different names `@`, `mail` & `server`. Yesterday you [had problems](https://serverfault.com/q/882388/274176) with the `PTR` record, now it's with the certificate.

1. Pick a single hostname for your service and use it everywhere. You could use `mailtuner.com` without a subdomain, as it's already in your certificate and was your `PTR` at least yesterday. That removes all mismatches.
2. More than one `MX` is for resiliency i.e. secondary mail servers allowing you to receive mail when the primary mail server as a final destination is down. Currently you have three `MX` records pointing eventually to the same IP address. That doesn't add anything but complexity.